# ActionColumn in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, php-7

The `ActionColumn` have `view`, `update`, `delete` by default.

I want to add a button "made" *to mark task as done*,( I have a column in db call *status* that get a int 0 or 1 ),
 so I want a function that implements the logic to mark the task as done, someone can help me with this ?

This example I get in the forum, but I don't understand very well

```
[
  'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
  'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} {made}',
  'buttons'=> [
    'made' => function () {     
      return Html::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>', [
        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'made'),
      ]);                                
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
[
  'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
  'template' => '{view} {update} {delete} {made}',
  'buttons'=> [
    ...
    'made' => function ($url, $model) {
       if($model->status === $model::STATUS_SUSPENDED){
          return Html::a("Activate", $url, [
              'title' => "Activate",
              'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-success',
              'data' => [
                   'method' => 'post',
                   'confirm' => 'Are you sure? This will Activate this.',
              ],
          ]);
       }
       return Html::a("Suspend", $url, [
          'title' => "Suspend",
          'class' => 'btn btn-xs btn-danger',
          'data' => [
              'method' => 'post',
              'confirm' => 'Are you sure? This will Suspend this.',
          ],
       ]);
     }
  ],
]
```

Then create method in your controller `actionMade()` where you check for `post` request, and perform necessary action on specified `id`. Hope this will helps.

Comment: I have a error saying "Undefined class constant 'STATUS_SUSPENDED' "

Comment: Sorry if I'm a noob in this, I have a challenge to make a crud with task manager in php + yii2, but i never had written a line of cod in this techs

Comment: You get error because this is a constants, which supposed to be in your model. defining the status of the entity. Learn Yii2 , it is easy to work with.